# How to fill a buffer with requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, buffer

I'm looking for how to keep filling a request buffer with chunks from an array of strings until all the chunks are done. Currently i have something like this:

```js
links: string[] // Array to check e.g. 2000 strings
chunkSize = 200;

from(links).pipe(
        bufferCount(chunkSize * 5),
        concatMap(links => {
          const linksToChunk = links;
          const chunks: Observable<string[]>[] = [];
          while (linksToChunk.length > 0) {
            const chunk: string[] = linksToChunk.splice(0, chunkSize);
            chunks.push(this.linkService.checkLinks(chunk));
          }
          return forkJoin(chunks);
        }),
        switchMap(chunks => [...chunks]) //Flatten array
      ).subscribe( 
        // Do stuff 
      )
```

However, what this does is making five request (5 times the chunk size) with 200  links each, and once all 5 requests are done, make another 5 etc. It works just five perfectly, but i rather have it continuously fill the buffer up. This is with rxjs v6.

Edit:
Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69914273/3884196)

Comment: You could use [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) and pass the maximum concurrent requests you want to make as the `concurrent` parameter

Comment: @NickL That was an excellent suggestion.

Comment: feel free to post your solution as the answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @NickL suggested using [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) this is what i ended up with:

```js
const concurrentRequests = 5;

from(links).pipe(
        bufferCount(chunkSize),
        mergeMap(chunk => this.linkService.checkLinks(chunk), concurrentRequests)
      ).subscribe( 
        // Do stuff 
      )
```

It now fill a chunk set by chunkSize each time a request is done and keeps doing so until all the links are chunked from the initial array of links, with a maximum of 5 simultaneous requests.